# ADT18 update but some style have mistake

Tags: android

i have update my ADt18.when i run my early app and sdk2.3,the eclipse give me mistake,the mistake appear at res\value\style, the detail is:

```
<style name="RatingBarSmall" parent="@android:Widget.RatingBar.Small">
 <style name="ListSeparator" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator.White">
```

i found the RatingBar.Small have not support,how to modify it. why update the adt
the style not to useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't allow anymore these kind of parents...

http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com.es/2011/08/new-to-android-more-style-restrictions.html